# Trying to change color of paintbrush for my drawing app

Tags: colors, processing

I'm trying to create a drawing program, using Processing 3.2.1, to make it so that when I press any number 1 - 0, the color changes based on the color assigned to the key, respectively. The problem that I'm facing is that I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. This is my code so far.

```java
float value = 255;
color c1 = color(0,0,0);
float e = 5;
float thickness = 1;
float max = 6;

void setup(){
  size (720,480);
  frameRate (120);
  background (255);
  fill (c1);
  stroke (c1);
}

void draw() 
{ 
 if(mousePressed) 
{ 
  if(thickness < max) 
    { 
    strokeWeight(thickness); 
    line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX,pmouseY); 
    thickness = thickness+0.25; 
    }
   else 
   { 
     line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX,pmouseY);
     strokeWeight(max);
   }
} 
}
void mouseReleased() 
{ 
thickness = thickness/thickness; 
}


void keyPressed (){
    if (key == '1') {
      c1 = color(255,0,0); //red
    }
    if (key == '2') {
      c1 = color(0,255,0); //green
    }
    if (key == '3') {
      c1 = color(0,0,255); //blue
    }
    if (key == '4') {
      c1 = color(255,255,0); //yellow
    }
    if (key == '5') {
      c1 = color(255,0,255); //magenta
    }
    if (key == '0') {
      c1 = color(255);
    }
    if (key == '9') {
      c1 = color(0);
    }
    if (key == '=') {
      e = e + 3;
      if (e > 100){
        e = 100;
      }
    }
    if (key == '-') {
      e = e - 3;
      if (e < 1){
        e = 1;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with _"it's not working"_? Do you get an error? Does the program not do what you expect? ...

Comment: I figured out my problem. It turns out I should have had fill and stroke in void draw() as opposed to void setup() :)

Comment: My problem was that the color of the line wasn't changing color. I then realized that my problem was where I had the fill statement

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're only setting the color (by calling the `fill()` and `stroke()` functions) **once**, in the `setup()` function. Even though you're changing the `c1` variable, that doesn't magically change the color.

To fix this, you either need to call the `fill()` and `stroke()` functions when you change the color in `keyPressed()`, or you could call them in the `draw()` function.

Also note that you could just call `noStroke()` if you don't want to have a different colored outline.